# Git seems to want to commit a vast number of files

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I lost Git on R-Studio and am trying to reinstall it on **Windows 8**.
When I click on the Git tab there is a long list (>100) of seemingly unrelated files presented.  A small sample inserted below.

[image]

What on earth have I done?

Comment: Have you set the project directory as `C:\ ` by any chance? There's probably a `.git` folder there if so. You don't really want to do that. Apart from that, this isn't really a question.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, that gave me a better idea of where to look.  It seems my company's IT permissions are confining Git to the Windows directory while my projects are in a different drive.  OK, perhaps not a question but a really frustrating problem and I do appreciate the time you took to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Final explanation: Git wouldn't accept UNC directory paths and defaulted to the C drive.  Solution: moved files to C drive.